# Making sure I'm connecting wiring in new ceiling fixture to the box

Tags: wiring, lighting, light-fixture

We wanted to replace a light fixture in our dining room, and I thought it would be straightforward, but I find myself second-guessing myself.

The fixture comes with four wires and instructions that are essentially nonexistent. I think "N" is neutral, "L" is load and the bare copper wire is ground. And this question said the wire with the horizontal lines and vertical line is also a ground?

[image: wiring from fixture]

And I'll be wiring into this box, which is switched and has a set of wires coming from the right (switch?) and one from the left (to continue the circuit?)

[image]

Am I on the right track that the Load wire goes to the black wires and the Neutral wire goes to the white wires.

And the ground wire with the horizontal lines and vertical line, that should go to the bare copper wire, while the fixture's bare copper wire should to the fixture bracket's ground screw and then to the other grounds?

EDIT: The switch works. It also controls four, recessed LED fixtures surrounding the fixture box.

Here's the old fixture. The wire with blue tape went to the black wires in the box. The neutral wire on the old fixture may have been not connected to the white wires in the box. I say may have because as I was taking it down, it wasn't really pigtailed to the others.

[image: old light fixture]

Comment: Grounds all go together - and should connect to the green screw on the bracket. A little concerned about the existing wires though. Was there a fixture previously? Are you sure the switch actually works? Are there any other lights on the same switch?

Comment: Is that how you found those wires in the ceiling box, or have you disconnected & reconnected some or all of them?

Comment: What's puzzling is that given the way it's wired right now, if the switch controls the light it also switches whatever is downstream from it.

Comment: Great questions. I updated and added edits to my original post.

Comment: Generally speaking, the bare wire would be the ground. However, there is _also_ an insulated wire with a grounding indication (circle with the lines in it). Can you show us a picture what these two wires connect to in the new fixture? It's possible that the bare wire grounds the fixture itself while the insulated wire grounds each of the lamp bases, though usually, they're not grounded.

Comment: The **old** fixture is ETL listed. What, if any test lab labeling is on the **new** fixture? It bears the hallmarks of "quite possibly unlisted direct import" and if that's the case, it should be returned, not connected. "CE" is not a listing and is probably fake, if that's the only apparent marking on the new fixture. Cheap fixtures that burn your house down are expensive.

Comment: @HoneyDo That's not particularly puzzling if there are multiple lights controlled by one switch, which s quite common.

Comment: @Ecnerwal the **new** fixture has a "SGS" mark on it. We purchased it from Lowe's but it does say made in China.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - Right. I understand that but there was no mention of another light.